# How to set position for div in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a container div and under container there are several div which i want to set position dynamically for an infinite page .now problem is when i am applying css by jquery  they are getting stuck in one place.i dont know how to loop through the inner divs

containerbox is the div which has to be run continuously and dynamically.....

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var w=$('.containerbox').width();
        var h=$('.containerbox').height();
        var conx=$(".containerbox").offset().left;
        var cony=$(".containerbox").offset().top;

        $('.containerbox').css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':w+conx,
            'top':h+10+'px'
        });

      });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
var w=$('.containerbox').width();
var h=$('.containerbox').height();
var conx=$(".containerbox").offset().left;
var cony=$(".containerbox").offset().top;

var currentHeight = h;

$('.containerbox div').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':w+conx,
        'top':currentHeight +10+'px' });

   currentHeight += h;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var w=$('.containerbox').width();
var h=$('.containerbox').height();
var conx=$(".containerbox").offset().left;
var cony=$(".containerbox").offset().top;

var height = h;
var width= w;

$('.containerbox').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':width+conx,
        'top':height+cony});
   height += h;// To make it infinite along y axis
   width +=w; // To make it infinite along x axis
});
```

Comment: actually containerbox is the div which is to be run in loop..there is no child div

Comment: Ya thanks sudip. Edited it now. It works for both x and y axis.

Comment: the top is not getting adjusted..what to do?? the structure is like a stair  :::

Comment: for top it is not working!!!!

Comment: How about this edition. sudip